# Iris outer boundary(Circle) detection using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, iris-recognition

How can I detect the outer boundary of an iris in an eye image.
I tried using HoughCircles() method,

```
        Gray cannyThreshold = new Gray(150);
        Gray cannyAccumulatorThreshold = new Gray(150);

        CircleF[] circles = grayscaledImg.HoughCircles(
                                     cannyThreshold,
                                     cannyAccumulatorThreshold,
                                     4,
                                     150,
                                     5,         //min radius
                                     0)[0];    //max radius



        foreach(CircleF circle in circles)
        {
            grayscaledImg.Draw(circle, new Gray(), 2);

        }
```

But the code draws the circle on the wrong places.
Need your help guys.

Output image:

[image]

Comment: Where does it draw the circle? Can you provide a picture?

Comment: This is the link to the picture http://i61.tinypic.com/157d5oj.png

Comment: Where did you apply canny filter?

Comment: I didn't apply canny filter but I increased the image brightness.

Comment: I'm new to image processing (EmguCV), so I only have little knowledge of Emgucv. Need someone to help with the boundary detection.

Comment: can you add the original (input) image without any brightness adjustments?

Comment: Im not using a single image for the project. The training dataset contains more than 200 images.

Comment: it may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890838/using-houghcircles-to-detect-and-measure-pupil-and-iris
and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567520/opencv-using-hough-circle-transformation-to-detect-iris